# QGIS report: picture rotation does not work properly

Tags: qgis

In my report shown in the picture below, I’d like to add a red arrow (as a picture) on top of the north arrow to visualize the direction I took the picture from. I added a integer field to my point feature, where I will enter the degrees of rotation (0-360).

Now, in the arrow's `item properties` under `position and size` I set the reference point to the centre.

If under `rotation`, I select my attribute field of the point feature where the rotation is stored, the red arrow leaves it’s place when creating the report. It literally jumps around the whole page (and even outside of it).

So I tested a workaround: If I create another (hidden) map, set the `map rotation` to my rotation attribute field and then set the `image rotation` of the red arrow to be synced with my hidden map, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know why there’s this difference?

What do you think about my workaround? Doesn’t it slow down my export too much? Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Picture pefore exporting - how it should be:
[image]

Picture after exporting - showing the jumping around:
[image]

Comment: I don't see the wild jumping around you mention.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added a picture showing the jumping around by editing my question.